# array package incompatible with stabular package

Tags: packages, incompatibility

I am not allowed to create new tags yet, so I apologize for not tagging this with the names of the particular packages as instructed.

I was trying to use both the [array](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) package and the [stabular](http://ctan.org/pkg/stabular) package, but apparently they are incompatible.  When both packages are loaded, the `tabular` environment doesn't work, nor does the `stabular`.

Is there a known work around so that the features of both are available in the same document?

Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{stabular}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
text & more text
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Any particular reasons to use `stabular` and not `longtable`, for example?

Comment: I have a headers file that has been developed over the years.  Some time back, I looked into `longtable`, `stabular` and other options.  At the time, `stabular` seemed to be the easiest way to accomplish what I was trying to do.  Consequently, all my files that utilize multipage tables are written with the `stabular` environment.  I'd rather not have to re-write all those files, so I was hoping there was a known workaround to this incompatibility.

Comment: @HTG: So what is it that you want to achieve? Usage of the [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) is pretty much ubiquitous, while [`stabular`](http://ctan.org/pkg/stabular) is not. If an incompatibility exists, it is most likely due to `stabular`.

Comment: Well, at a simplistic level, I'm just wanting to keep the same header file that I've developed, but now include the `array` package so I can access the `>{commands}` feature. But previous documents utilize the `stabular` package, and I didn't want to have to re-write them for `longtable`.  But, if that's what I have to do, I will.  Bleah.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way that `stabular.sty` and `array.sty` can live together, as they both want to redefine the important macro `\@mkpream` that's responsible for building a suitable internal code from the argument to a `tabular` environment.

They also redefine `\@tabularcr` (the internal version of the user command `\\`) in incompatible ways.

I don't think that there's something possible with `stabular` which isn't with `longtable`.